# Can you submit apps to the Google Play Store made with Android Studios 2.2?

Tags: android, google-play

This may be a dumb question, but I do not want to waste my time creating an app and then finding out I have to wait till Android Studios 2.2 officially comes out. I want to download and start using Android Studios 2.2 and use the new constraints layout they added, but it if not officially out. Does anyone know if apps created in Android 2.2 can be submitted to the Google Play Store?

Comment: why would the IDE you use matter at all? it is not android studio that makes the build, it is gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Well of course you can.

I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to. All you need to upload an App to the Play Store would be your GMail Account, A Google Developer Account (with your GMail account), and then you can upload your APK using the Developer Console. I am not updated to the specific details you have to fill out but I'm pretty sure that as long as you have a good APK file (that isn't violating any privacy rules) then I think you're good to go.

Comment: Alright, I am going to get started on 2.2 now thanks for the info!

Comment: Don't forget to hit the check mark if my post answered your question.